# ImageMagick: convert [label:]

Tags: imagemagick-convert

There is a command:

```
/Path_to/convert \
-background LightBlue1 \
-border 10 \
-bordercolor red \
-font Helvetica-Bold-Oblique \
-fill blue \
-pointsize 72 \
label:\
"\n`date "+DATE: %Y-%m-%d%nTIME: %H:%M:%S"`\n\n\
--Text!--" \
"/Users/user/Pictures/Test_Image.png"
```

The command works correctly (the image file is being created

```
identify /Users/user/Pictures/Test_Image.png
/Users/user/Pictures/Test_Image.png PNG 647x386 647x386+0+0 16-bit sRGB 45148B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

), but I need to "--Text! -" it was printed with other font, color and size, rather than the rest of the text.

My attempts to solve this failed.

How to do it?

Thankful in advance for the help!

P.S.

```
convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.9-40 Q16 x86_64 2018-07-28 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2018 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype gslib jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma openexr png ps raw tiff webp x xml zlib 

uname -a
Darwin Air.local 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Mon Jan 11 18:17:34 PST 2016; root:xnu-2422.115.15~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean by `"but I need to "--Text! -" it was printed with other font, color and size, rather than the rest of the text."` Please clarify. If you need to change fonts or colors etc, then you will have to use label: multiple time and merge the resulting images. If you know the output size ahead of time, you can use -annotate twice in the same command line and change fonts. But you cannot do that in one command line with label:

Comment: The Imagemagick command for creating text called pango: rather than label: allows you to create text of different fonts and colors in one command. See https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/ But you need to do that in Pango markup language.